# Структура проекта для Maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Чтобы упростить понимание моего вопроса, я максимально упрощу ситуацию.
У меня есть проекы Hotel и Configurator. Оба созданы в *intellij-idea*. Для того, чтобы запустить Hotel, мне нужна jar-ка проекта Configurator. Я ее подключаю в idea, чтобы запустить проект.
Теперь мне нужно перевести проект на *Maven*. Я создал нужную для этого структуру в проекте Hotel.

Вопрос:
Как мне теперь подключить jar-ку конфигуратора? Или мне нужно объединить 2 проекта в один? Т.е., допустим, я делаю Hotel, а другой человек делает Configurator. Как в *Maven* должны объединяться эти проекты? Не знаю, как в жизни это происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте install вашего Configurator проекта. (Он установится в ваш локальный репозиторий). Затем подключите его как dependency в вашем проекте Hotel.

Comment: Т.е. чтобы собрать весь проект, мне нужно все подключаемые проекты(Configurator например) установить в локальный репозиторий? Это нормальная практика? У меня их 10 штук просто, и все нужно пихать туда?

Comment: @andreyatake Если у вас 10 отдельных проектов (артефактов), которые не включаются друг в друга, то да - вам нужно установить все в локальный репозиторий, а потом подключить как зависимости в основном проекте. Если у вас какие-то артефакты включаются друг в друга, то в главном проекте нужно сделать exclude, чтобы жары не повторялись. Либо подключать не все 10,а скажем 5 (при условии, что в эти 5 включаются остальные 5 как транзитивные зависимости)